# Development of a Suite Application with modules download for iPhone

Tags: iphone, plugins, module, download, suite

I'm starting developing applications for iPhone. My idea is to develop a application like a suite or multiple modules. The main application function is a application manager. This application can download each of the availables applications for the suite, like a office suite that starts with no applications/extensions, so, there are the possibility to download a spread-sheet editor, a text editor, or a image editor and so on.

I don't know if each application need to be a standalone application in appstore and the manager to have only shortcuts for they. Or if each application can be a library or plugin that will be installed in the main application through download.

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App store review guidelines says:

> 2.7 Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected

You can't download libraries or code in your application. What you can do is, ship the application with all functionalities and enable them by in-app purchases.

Comment: This way, there is no form to link other applications? I can't create shortcuts from the main application to installed software?
And, and when necessary to download other plugin, I redirect the user to appstore to download a full application related to the suite. This extension, to be in the appstore, it has been validated by the Apple team.

Comment: Redirecting users to other apps on appstore, by embedding the links in your app is perfectly acceptable, but downloading new components is not. Moreover if your new downloaded apps have customs URLs, you may also invoke them from your already existing app.

Comment: Thank You! Now I will search something how to check installed apps in the device. The good thing is I will develop all applications, both the main software as the others. This way, I will have more alternatives to control the process.